# exit code for rsync if there is no modification done to destination folder

Tags: unix, solaris, rsync

I'm using rsync in solaris and couldn't find an exit code if there is no file or folder modification/addition or deletion done on the destination folder. How can I get the status if rsync doesn't have one ?

```
 0     Success
 1     Syntax or usage error
 2     Protocol incompatibility
 3     Errors selecting input/output files, dirs
 4     Requested action not supported: an attempt was made to manipulate 64-bit
       files on a platform that cannot support them; or an option was specified
       that is supported by the client and not by the server.
 5     Error starting client-server protocol
 6     Daemon unable to append to log-file
10     Error in socket I/O
11     Error in file I/O
12     Error in rsync protocol data stream
13     Errors with program diagnostics
14     Error in IPC code
20     Received SIGUSR1 or SIGINT
21     Some error returned by waitpid()
22     Error allocating core memory buffers
23     Partial transfer due to error
24     Partial transfer due to vanished source files
25     The --max-delete limit stopped deletions
30     Timeout in data send/receive
35     Timeout waiting for daemon connection
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a work around

```
rsync --log-format=%f ...
```

Note that rsync outputs files anytime any attribute changes, not only if the content of the file is updated.

There is also a -i option (or --log-format=%i) that itemizes all of the changes. See the rsync man page for details of the output format.